# ENSideSwiftMenu: how to use same Navigation Bar for all View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am using [Evgeny Nazarov's Swift Side Menu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) for my iOS app and was wondering if anyone has used this same library and able to have the same Navigation Bar for every `View Controller` that is called from the menu.

I put a `BarButtonItem` that toggles the sliding menu on my `Root View Controller`. My problem is that only my `Root View Controller` shows this Toggle Button. But I would like to have that same `Navigation Bar` with the `Toggle` button on every `View Controller` that is accessible when clicking an option on the sliding menu.

Has anyone had an experience achieving this? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

This is what happens when I added a `NavigationBar` and `BarButtonItem` to the other `ViewControllers` that aren't the `RootViewController`. The new Navigation Bar ends up under the existing Navigation Bar from the Navigation Controller.

The screen on the left is the `Root View Controller` and the one on the right is the `View Controller` when I select the second item on the menu.

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let menuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon_menu"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "menuBarButtonItemClicked")
    menuItem.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem
}

func menuBarButtonItemClicked() {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a UIBarButtonItem on the navigation bar in every view controller, not in the root view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made an update to my original post. Please see above. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add a NavigationBar. Can you access to rootViewController's NavigationBar through self.navigationController.navigationBar ?

Comment: so I would have to add the `BarButtonItem` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I too have used the same design for my app and I solved it this way:
View every sect "**Show the Attribute Inspector** -> **Top bar**" the voice "**Translucent Navigation Bar**", then drag the "**Navigation Item**" and then "**Bar Button Item**" in the position you want. Of course every button should have its code or references to the ViewController.
Let me know if you have solved.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I solved it following evnaz's instructions. Check my `UPDATE 2` in my op to see the code. I added this to every view controller.

Comment: Oh sorry, from the iPhone will not charge fully so I could not see the update 2, and then I responded with my solution.